# Rails cant connect to database with ActiveRecord::establish_connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am opening rails console session and do:

```rb
2.6.3 :048 > ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
 => true 
2.6.3 :049 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
 => [] 
2.6.3 :050 > ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
 => false 
2.6.3 :051 > ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)
 => #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x00 ... >
2.6.3 :052 > ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
 => false
2.6.3 :053 > SomeModel.connection
 => #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x00 ...>
2.6.3 :055 > ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
 => true
```

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.2.3
```

my `config/database.yml` file has to be fine, because HTTP requests are working fine.

Why I cant establish connection in rails console this way?

I am asking because I have similar use of `establish_connection` in one of `config/initializers/` file, that is configuring [sneakers](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers) workers [like here](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/issues/67#issuecomment-53819227) and there it is also returning me `false` on `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect again you can use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connect
```

AR calls establish_connection only once, for ActiveRecord::Base. All subclasses use the one connection.

You can manually call establish connection yourself on some subclasses. This is very convenient for using two databases at once, e.g.

```
class MyMainUser < ActiveRecord::Base; end 
class MyOtherDb < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class MyOtherUser < MyOtherDb; end

MyOtherDb.establish_connection ...

MyMainUser.first # uses default db
MyOtherUser.first # uses other db
You can't do queries that would cross databases though.
```

Comment: thats right, but there should be `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`

Answer (score 1):

To connect you can use ActiveRecord::Base.connection and than you can call Somemodel.first and its should work.